# SQL - Cut string upto a string (first one only)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a string like this:

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(max)
set @val='id=1 and Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32'
```

Now i need to cut the string only **upto the end of first and**.here id length can be 1-100000.So i can fixed a length.
Current situation: `id=1 and Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32`
Expected result: `Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @val='id=1 and Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32' 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('% and%', @val) + 4, LEN(@val))
```

- [SQLFiddle *Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6417)

Other Links

- [PATINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)
- [LEN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)
- [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @val1 int

set @val='id=1 and Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32' 

set @val1=CHARINDEX('Name', @val)
select val2=SUBSTRING(@val,@val1,LEN(@val)-(@val1-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are after something like this should get you want you want:

```
substring(@val , CHARINDEX(@val) + 4, len(@val))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can also do it without a call of `LEN` and `SUBSTRING` method.

Something like this would help:

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(max)
set @val='id=1 and Name=abc and Address=NY and age=32' 

Select @val as OriginalValue
select stuff(@val,1,charindex('d ',@val) + 1,'') as ExpectedResult
```

We need a call of `STUFF` method along with `CHARINDEX`.

Check out [how STUFF works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

**Remember:** STUFF is `position oriented` (starts with 1).

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use substring function like

```
@val=substring('@val',9,'remaining char')
```

see: SUBSTRING(), CHARINDEX(), PATINDEX()

refer here

http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_function_substring.php